# SQL Sum of differences getting different results

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
WITH
    FOO as(
        SELECT 
            IF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_key) > 9,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_key) || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_key),
            EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_key) || '0' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_key))  AS YEAR_MONTH,
            cast(ITEM_KEY AS INT) AS ITEM_KEY,
            cast(STORE_KEY AS INT) AS STORE_KEY,
            MAIN_SUPPLIER_KEY AS SUPPLIER_KEY,
            SUM(SAL_QTY_CMP_NPCE_XTAX) AS SAL_QTY_CMP_NPCE_XTAX, -- 3º KPI CUSTO_FINANCEIRO CR4
            SUM(SAL_AMT_XTAX) - SUM(SAL_QTY_CMP_NPCE_XTAX) AS MARGEM_BRUTA, -- 8º KPI MARGEM_BRUTA CR4
            SUM(SAL_AMT_XTAX) AS SAL_AMT_XTAX, -- 14º KPI VENDA_LIQUIDA CR4
            'CR4' AS ORIGEM
        FROM `foo`
        GROUP BY YEAR_MONTH,ITEM_KEY,STORE_KEY,SUPPLIER_KEY
    ),

    BAR AS (
     SELECT YEAR_MONTH,
        ITEM_KEY,
        STORE_KEY,
        SUPPLIER_KEY,
        SUM(SAL_AMT_XTAX) as SAL_AMT_XTAX,
        sum(SAL_QTY_CMP_NPCE_XTAX) as SAL_QTY_CMP_NPCE_XTAX,
        sum(MARGEM_BRUTA) as MARGEM_BRUTA,
        ORIGEM
     FROM
        FOO
    GROUP BY YEAR_MONTH,ITEM_KEY,STORE_KEY,SUPPLIER_KEY,ORIGEM
)


select  SUM(SAL_AMT_XTAX) - SUM(SAL_QTY_CMP_NPCE_XTAX)  as MARGEM1,  --213465264
        sum(MARGEM_BRUTA)                               AS MARGEM2   --213461382
from BAR
```

The calculation of MARGEM1 and MARGEM2 are conceptually the same. However, I'm getting slightly different numbers in the end:

**MARGEM1:** 213465264

**MARGEM2:** 213461382

I'm kinda confused. How it gave me different result as it is supposed to be the same formula but calculated at different times? Feel free to as me any further information you'd like. I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: When you do `SUM(SAL_AMT_XTAX) - SUM(SAL_QTY_CMP_NPCE_XTAX)` inside `FOO` if either of the `sum`s are null you lose the information about the other `sum`. e.g. `10 - null` is `null` not `10`. You can do `COALESCE(SUM(SAL_AMT_XTAX),0) - COALESCE(SUM(SAL_QTY_CMP_NPCE_XTAX),0)` to avoid this

Comment: As general if data types are different (say one decimal and one int) you can/will loose the decimal places.  You would have to convert the int to the same datatype as decimal then running math on them will return same data type.

Comment: `MARGEM_BRUTA` is not computed correctly in the presence of nulls. Validate and rewrite that expression to compute values that make sense.

Comment: You were right. The presence of nulls made the difference. Adding the coalesce solution given by Martin resolved my problem. Thank you all for the insights.